# Getting Realtek drivers to reach Gigabit speed under Ubuntu is nigh impossible

Tags: ubuntu, performance, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet

I have a HP Touchsmart TM2 2105 laptop, quite recently bought. The NIC is Gigabit speed capable, with a Realtek R8168  chipset.

I installed the drivers from Realtek, it works, `ethtools` indicates 1000Mpbs. But a simple download test with a Windows PC shows a maximum speed of 130 Mbits. The same test, with the same hardware, but with the laptop under Windows (on another partition) shows approximately 500 Mbps.

I don't know what to do?

The other machine and the switch are gigabit capable, since, the download test with the same machines but under Windows gives approximately 500 Mbps.

I will try MTU and let you know.

If I test under Linux with the command `iperf`, I get app 650 Mbps!

edit : with MTU= 9000 -> no difference :(

Comment: 1) Are you sure the speed you are seeing is 130 megabits per second, and not 130 megabytes per second?  A gigabit NIC is going to top out at a little under 130 megabytes per second.  2) I suggest you see if you can turn on jumbo frames (MTU > 1500), and if you can, whether that helps.

Comment: Is the OTHER machine GigaBit capable?  Is your router?  switch?  Unless you're directly connecting the two machines, there's other stops on the cable to consider.  But @Slartibartfast has a point, doing the math gives 130MBps (Bytes) theoretical top speed.

Comment: Of course, I missed the part about it being same machine, different stats.  My mistake.  Jumbo frames will likely improve your throughput, as linux doesn't enable them by default, whereas Windows might.

Comment: Well, the last time I had this sort of issue on Linux, it had to do with the Ethernet cable connecting the Ubuntu machine to the networking switch/router. I replaced the cable, and it went back to `926Mbits/s`. Obviously, you need to have Gigabit cable gear all along the route to the other computer (running `iperf`, I guess), along with good cables.

Comment: PS: BTW, the max I could push things on the link was about `960Mbits/s` using 10 parallel streams of UDP pumping at `125MB/s`. I.e., `iperf -c <serverIP> -u -P 10 -i 1 -p 5001 -f k -b 125.0M -t 10 -T 1`